# How to parse multidimensional json array in java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a two dimensional JSON array object like below

```
{"enrollment_response":{"condition":"Good","extra":"Nothig","userid":"526398"}}
```

I would like to parse the above Json array object to get the condition, extra, userid.So i have used below code

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    try {

        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("D:\\document(2).json"));

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

        String name = (String) jsonObject.get("enrollment_response");
        System.out.println("Condition:" + name);

        String name1 = (String) jsonObject.get("extra");
        System.out.println("extra: " + name1);



    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Its throwing an error as

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to java.lang.String at
com.jsonparser.apps.JsonParsing1.main(JsonParsing1.java:22)"
```

Please anyone help on this issue.

Comment: What json lib do you use?

Comment: I think the error message is pretty clear. What result are you hoping to get by casting an **object** to a **string** (you do realize that the value of `enrollment_response` is an object?)?

Comment: What you have here is not an array at all. It is a Json object with another Json object nested in.

Comment: I would like to get the values of condition,extra and userid

Comment: FYI `org.json.simple` is quite possibly the *worst* JSON parsing library you could possibly choose. Please, please use something else. Jackson, Gson, or even the old json.org libs are far better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: **Do not use the JSON parsing library you're using**. It's horrible. No, really, *horrible*. It's an old, crufty thing that lightly wraps a Java rawtype Hashmap. It can't even handle a JSON array as the root structure.

Use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), or even the old [json.org library](http://www.json.org/java/index.html).

That said, to fix your current code:

```
JSONObject enrollmentResponseObject = 
    (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("enrollment_response");
```

This gets the inner object. Now you can extract the inner fields:

```
String condition = (String) enrollmentResponseObject.get("condition");
```

And so forth. The whole library simply extends a `Hashmap` (without using generics) and makes you figure out and cast to the appropriate types.

Answer (score 2):

Below line,

```
String name = (String) jsonObject.get("enrollment_response");
```

should be

```
String name = jsonObject.getJSONObject("enrollment_response").getString("condition");
```

Value of `enrollment_response` is again a Json.

Comment: I get an error message as "The method getJSONObject(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject"

Comment: Can you provide the fully qualified class name for `JSONObject`. I assumed you are using [org.json](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#get%28java.lang.String%29) library.

Comment: @ShashankKadne It's org.json.simple and it's awful.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but trust me: change library.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

JSONObject name = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("enrollment_response");
System.out.println("Condition:" + name);

String name1 = (String) name.get("extra");
System.out.println("extra: " + name1);
```

Comment: Hi enrichman i got an error as "The method getJSONObject(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject"

Comment: As the other answerer posted we thought you were using the org.json library. Can you provide the exact library you're using?

Comment: @BrianRoach can I suggest you to switch over the standard and more documented org.json or Jackson?

Comment: @Enrichman *I'm* not the OP; I was pointing out what lib they're using ;) See my answer.

Comment: @BrianRoach ahaha, sorry, you're right! Never seen such an awful JSON library btw. I had to download it to understand it.